# How to rid of Java warning re: input or output annotation?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm writing a Gradle plugin in Java, and I have a class with some attributes. When I compile, I get these warnings,

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import java.io.*;

public class MyClass extends DefaultTask {
  ...
  String dstBranch=null;
  ...
}

property 'dstBranch' is not annotated with an input or output annotation
```

I read about annotations, and tried

```
public class MyClass extends DefaultTask {
  ...
  @Input
  String dstBranch=null;
  ...
}
```

But I get the compiler error

```
Incompatible types: Input cannot be converted to annotation
```

How do I rid of the warnings?

Comment: What `Input` are you importing? Is it `org.gradle.api.tasks.Input`?

Comment: Show us your import pls.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca and @Tristate, thanks. Your comments made me realize I needed this `import org.gradle.api.tasks.Input;` If you want to provide this as an answer I can mark it as one.

Comment: @ChrisF there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely importing the wrong `Input`.

You need

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Input;
```